# Display array element ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

UPD: How can I display elment of the array in my component (WeatherCityName - h2)? It can be seen that the array is loaded, but when I point out the property - an error occurs, it may be a problem in the syntax?

```
  var WeatherBox = React.createClass({
   handleWeatherSubmit: function(text) {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'cityName=' + text,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="wetherBox">
      <h1> Weather</h1>
      <WeatherForm onWeatherSubmit={this.handleWeatherSubmit} />
      <WeatherCityName data={this.state.data[0]} />
      <WeatherList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var WeatherCityName = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <h2>{this.state.data[0].cityName}</h2>
            );
    }
});
```

[image: Error]

[image: React]

Comment: What are you trying to do with `this.props(function(weatherItem) { ... });`? Also, put that JSX on the same line as the return.

Comment: I'm trying to return <h2></h2> only once.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put `<h2>{weatherItem.cityName}</h2>` directly in the `<div>`.

```
var WeatherList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var weatherNodes = this.props.data.map(function(weatherItem) {
      return (
        <div className="city-item-with-title">
          <h2>{weatherItem.cityName}</h2>
          <WeatherItem 
            cityid={weatherItem.cityid}
            type={weatherItem.type} 
            src={weatherItem.src} 
            temp={weatherItem.temp} 
            tempFrom={weatherItem.tempFrom} 
            tempTo={weatherItem.tempTo} 
            key={weatherItem.id}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="weatherList">
        {weatherNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

- Edit: I'm not sure *which* weather item you want to use as a title, perhaps `this.props.data[0]`?
- Edit 2: Just assumed you want to use the first weather item.
- Edit 3: One title for each weatherItem, grouped inside a div together with the corresponding weatherItem.

Comment: this variant causes an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: weatherItem is not defined.` Data in json format: `[{"id": 1, "cityName": "Kiev","typeid": 1, "type": "morning", "src": "www", "tempFrom":"+1", "tempTo": "+2"},
{"id": 1, "cityName": "Kiev","typeid": 1, "type": "morning", "src": "www", "tempFrom":"+1", "tempTo": "+2"},]`  I need to show them the method map, but `"cityName"`  I need displayed only once in `<h2>`

Comment: Yes, my answer was a little unclear. inside `<h2>{weatherItem.cityName}</h2>` weatherItem is not defined. Which weatherItem do you want to use for the title?

Comment: I added all the code. `weatherItem` - this is an array in json format. And I need to display cityTitle `(cityName = "Kiev")`  in `h2` only once, and other data in the method `map`

Comment: Ok, always Kiev? Then just `<h2>Kiev</h2>`

Comment: No, not always. `cityname` and data changed and loaded via ajax

Comment: Do you want one `<h2>{wietherItem.cityId}</h2>` for each weatherItem? Or just for one of them?

Comment: just for one of them

Comment: No, just one for all of them

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer so you get one title for each weather item. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Probably not I clearly explain( I need title only one on the page and a few weather item. But my data.json file containes title (cityName) of each elements of the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128388/discussion-between-i-swen-and-arnehugo).